# Theory or Direction, c++, qt and crosscompiling with MXE

Tags: c++, qt, cross-compiling, mxe

I am after a little bit of help, not an issue for someone to fix but more theory or the right path to go down would be helpful. I am quite new with C, C++. But I offered help to friend and have become a little stuck myself.

I am cross-compiling for Windows a project in MXE. The project uses QT 4 (QTCore, QTGui, QTNetwork and QTWebKit), Boost, OpenSSL, BerkelyDB.

Now before he added QTWebKit I was able to compile the project using **i686-w64-mingw32.static**, I understand due to library conflicts with QTScript that MXE Cannot compile QTWebKit with static and this requires it to be compiled with **i686-w64-mingw32.shared**

Now, The exe compiles in **i686-w64-mingw32.shared** but requires about 35 different DLL libraries with it to run including libgcc* dlls. Even though the .pro or makefile has **-static-libgcc** & **-static-libstdc++**

So my question is.

**Is there a way to compile this project so that most of the libraries are static, the ones that can be, like libgcc* & boost and only a few like QTWebKit are dynamic or (shared?)?**

I appreciate any help that you can offer in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [TDM-mingw](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download)
OR
build your custom MinGW-GCC from source and make all libraries static link by default.

Comment: Edited the makefile a little and used this instead of standard mingw. Worked perfect first time, Thanks for your suggestion.